# Javascript toLocaleTimeString() Returning ASCII 226 Instead of Space in Latest Version of Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

We use the Javascript function toLocaleTimeString() to parse date/times. The newest version of Chrome is returning an ASCII 226 between the seconds and the AM/PM part of the time suddenly. Edge is not having any issues nor are older versions of Chrome. 110+ has the issue and 109 or earlier does not.

For example, if the last couple of characters returned are:

00 AM

The ASCII translation of that is:

48 48 226 128 175

That 226 used to be a 32 (space).

Anyone else seeing this behavior as well?

Comment: (swear words) This just cost us thousands of dollars in lost productivity. What a profoundly dumb change. I see that the discussion among the Mozilla developers on Bugzilla says things like, "it only affects bad code using naive parsing." No, I'm just sanitizing a time string and passing it to the database, which now says, "(shrug) I don't know what this time string is." They've confused formatting for display with formatting for all other purposes. I've worked around it for now by doing a string replace of this narrow no-break space character with a regular space before I process it further.

Comment: I just noticed that Chrome 110.0.5481.178 has a separator of 32 (space).

Answer (score 7):

This is apparently caused by [this V8 CL](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/2ada52cffbff11074abfaac18938bf02d85454f5)

Here is the summary of this ChangeLog:

> [intl] Enhance Date parser to take Unicode SPACE
>
> This is needed to prepare for the landing of ICU72.
> Allow U+202F in the Date String, which the toLocaleString("en-US")
> will generate w/ ICU72.

So it's done on purpose, to support the [next version of ICU-72](https://icu.unicode.org/download/72). We can thus assume that other browsers will also follow on this.

#### [Update]

Since this change caused [too many web-compat issues](https://crbug.com/1414292), Chrome did patch their Intl implementation against this ICU-72 change and converted these U+202F characters back to U+2000 characters. Apparently, [Firefox did the same](https://bugzil.la/1806042#c17) even before.

Comment: Interesting: my browser just updated and it's putting an ASCII space in there again. Version 110.0.5481.97

Comment: @user1488803 indeed, they actually did patch their Intl implementation to go against ICU-72 (Firefox did the same).

Answer (score 3):

I think it's non-breaking space.
[Non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space)

Since it also occurs on Edge110, I think it is derived from Chromium.

```js
const event = new Date('August 19, 1975 23:15:30 GMT+00:00');
const localTime = event.toLocaleTimeString('en-US');
console.log(localTime);
console.log(localTime.indexOf(" "))
console.log(localTime.indexOf("\u{202F}"))
for (let i = 0; i < localTime.length; i++){
  console.log(localTime.charCodeAt(i));
}
```